# Google Analytics click event not working, hitCallback also not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a text box on a web page that shows partial text and displays the rest of the paragraph when the user clicks on a "see full text" icon. We want to use google analytics to track how many users click on this icon.

Analytics is correctly tracking active sessions in live view, but no matter what I try, it cannot see the click events. There are no messages in the console.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.view-text').click(function(e) {
        ga('send', {
            'hitType': 'event',         
            'eventCategory': 'button', 
            'eventAction': 'Home',     
            'eventLabel': 'View Text',
            'nonInteraction': true
        });
    });
});
```

That was my code to send the events, but when I go to the analytics account Reports > Real-Time > Events, there are no events shown. I've clicked the box dozens of times now. I do see "1 active users on site" as expected.

To troubleshoot, I added a console.log in the click handler, which is showing up, so I know the ga function is being called. I then tried to add a 'hitCallback' option with an alert, and the 'alert' is **NOT** firing, but I don't know why that could be.

I'm wondering if I'm looking in the wrong place in the google analytics dashboard, or maybe I missed a step in the setup?

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.view-text').click(function(e) {
        console.log('clickie');
        ga('send', {
            'hitType': 'event',         
            'eventCategory': 'button', 
            'eventAction': 'Home',     
            'eventLabel': 'View Text',
            'hitCallback' : function () {
                alert("Event received");
            },
            'nonInteraction: true
        });
    });
});
```

I've also tried this alternate syntax:

```
ga('send','event','button','Home','View Text', {
    nonInteraction: true
});
```

Thanks very much SO for any help.

Comment: Is there anything on your site that could have renamed/superseded the ga function? I know some third-part plugins (WordPress) can alter this.

Comment: That's a possibility. It is a wordpress site. I ran "console.log(ga)" and it returned this:
ƒ (a){J(1);Z.D.apply(Z,[arguments])}
But I'm not sure what I was expecting.

Comment: Well it looks like something is there! I think it might be the Yoast SEO plugin that changes the function.

Comment: We're not using Yoast, so that's not it...

Answer (score 0):

Is it that your object properties are strings?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Note on the above link that properties in the fieldsObject are *not* in quotation marks. Also, you have a syntax error on nonInteraction (missing closing quotation).

Comment: Even copying and pasting their exact example doesn't produce any results:
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');

Comment: I am seeing the same thing right now. Extremely aggravating. Did you ever find a resolution?